# When enabled stemming, searching for the root word gives no hits

Tags: solr, stemming

I have indexed a site with solr. It works very well if stemming is not enabled. Using stemming, however, solr does not return any hits when searching for the root of a word. I use Swedish stemming.

For example, searching for `support` gives hits if not using stemming. Using stemming, searching for `support` gives no hits. Though, searching for `supporten` returns hits that match `support`.

By debugging the query, I can see that it stems the word `support` to `suppor` (which is incorrect by the way, but that should not matter). However, having the word stemmed to `suppor`, I want it to search for matches with the the original query word as well.

I'd appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, there is no way to keep the original word when stemming...

I assume that you are using `solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory`. Snowball algorithm is too aggressive.

You should try a [Hunspell stemmer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HunspellStemFilterFactory) or maybe `solr.SwedishLightStemFilterFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround you can do is to reformat your query into "support support*" or "support support~". * is wildcard matching and ~ is fuzzy matching using Lucene syntax. I know you didn't mention the need to do wildcard and fuzzy search, but I found under these circumstances, the stemming on query will not take effect, so "support" is preserved. And stemming will still be effective on the first word, so both results will be returned if any. Plus, fuzzy search will help reduce the tolerance of typos in users' queries, so it's an added benefit.